# Access to permission files

Tags: android, file-io

I am trying to connect a zwave device to android tv box.

For that I need to edit **handheld_core_hardware.xml** file situated in */system/etc/permissions*, but I can't do that since it is a read only file.

Can somebody tell me any trick by which I can edit the file?

Comment: Probably being root could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot access that file without root (superuser) permissions.**

Every files located in /data or /system dirs are protected and you can read or write it only with root permissions.

Try something different or your app will run only on rooted devices.

Read more about that :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_rooting

http://www.androidcentral.com/root